# keras tensorboard: plot train and validation scalars in a same figure

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, tensorboard

So I am using tensorboard within keras. In tensorflow one could use two different summarywriters for train and validation scalars so that tensorboard could plot them in a same figure. Something like the **figure** in

[TensorBoard - Plot training and validation losses on the same graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146614/tensorboard-plot-training-and-validation-losses-on-the-same-graph)

Is there a way to do this in keras?

Thanks.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To handle the validation logs with a separate writer, you can write a custom callback that wraps around the original `TensorBoard` methods.

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

class TrainValTensorBoard(TensorBoard):
    def __init__(self, log_dir='./logs', **kwargs):
        # Make the original `TensorBoard` log to a subdirectory 'training'
        training_log_dir = os.path.join(log_dir, 'training')
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).__init__(training_log_dir, **kwargs)

        # Log the validation metrics to a separate subdirectory
        self.val_log_dir = os.path.join(log_dir, 'validation')

    def set_model(self, model):
        # Setup writer for validation metrics
        self.val_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.val_log_dir)
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).set_model(model)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # Pop the validation logs and handle them separately with
        # `self.val_writer`. Also rename the keys so that they can
        # be plotted on the same figure with the training metrics
        logs = logs or {}
        val_logs = {k.replace('val_', ''): v for k, v in logs.items() if k.startswith('val_')}
        for name, value in val_logs.items():
            summary = tf.Summary()
            summary_value = summary.value.add()
            summary_value.simple_value = value.item()
            summary_value.tag = name
            self.val_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)
        self.val_writer.flush()

        # Pass the remaining logs to `TensorBoard.on_epoch_end`
        logs = {k: v for k, v in logs.items() if not k.startswith('val_')}
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).on_train_end(logs)
        self.val_writer.close()
```

- In `__init__`, two subdirectories are set up for training and validation logs
- In `set_model`, a writer `self.val_writer` is created for the validation logs
- In `on_epoch_end`, the validation logs are separated from the training logs and written to file with `self.val_writer`

Using the MNIST dataset as an example:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[TrainValTensorBoard(write_graph=False)])
```

You can then visualize the two curves on a same figure in TensorBoard.

[image: Screenshot]

---

**EDIT:** I've modified the class a bit so that it can be used with eager execution.

The biggest change is that I use `tf.keras` in the following code. It seems that the `TensorBoard` callback in standalone Keras does not support eager mode yet.

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.python.eager import context

class TrainValTensorBoard(TensorBoard):
    def __init__(self, log_dir='./logs', **kwargs):
        self.val_log_dir = os.path.join(log_dir, 'validation')
        training_log_dir = os.path.join(log_dir, 'training')
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).__init__(training_log_dir, **kwargs)

    def set_model(self, model):
        if context.executing_eagerly():
            self.val_writer = tf.contrib.summary.create_file_writer(self.val_log_dir)
        else:
            self.val_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.val_log_dir)
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).set_model(model)

    def _write_custom_summaries(self, step, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        val_logs = {k.replace('val_', ''): v for k, v in logs.items() if 'val_' in k}
        if context.executing_eagerly():
            with self.val_writer.as_default(), tf.contrib.summary.always_record_summaries():
                for name, value in val_logs.items():
                    tf.contrib.summary.scalar(name, value.item(), step=step)
        else:
            for name, value in val_logs.items():
                summary = tf.Summary()
                summary_value = summary.value.add()
                summary_value.simple_value = value.item()
                summary_value.tag = name
                self.val_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
        self.val_writer.flush()

        logs = {k: v for k, v in logs.items() if not 'val_' in k}
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self)._write_custom_summaries(step, logs)

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        super(TrainValTensorBoard, self).on_train_end(logs)
        self.val_writer.close()
```

The idea is the same --

- Check the source code of `TensorBoard` callback
- See what it does to set up the writer
- Do the same thing in this custom callback

Again, you can use the MNIST data to test it,

```py
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.train import AdamOptimizer

tf.enable_eager_execution()

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
y_train = y_train.astype(int)
y_test = y_test.astype(int)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=AdamOptimizer(), metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[TrainValTensorBoard(write_graph=False)])
```

Comment: Hello Yu, is there a way to log validation accuracy and loss each batch (instead of each epoch)? We have plenty of images to train, and one epoch may take several minutes to update once.

Comment: yes Hao Xi.You can add a counter variable in on_batch_end method and use it to log for every 'n' batches. You can see the code in [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6692#issuecomment-373929106) github issue.

Comment: Hello Yu, is this also possible with eager execution enabled? That means can this code also be updated to use the TensorFlow Summary API v2 (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/summary)?

Comment: @Derk I've updated the answer to include an example with eager execution enabled (tested with TF 1.11.0). Please see if it matches your use case.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason you use summary_ops_v2 and not the standard API as in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/summary

Comment: Actually both should work fine. But that's a good point. The standard API might be stabler than the internal API. I'll edit my answer to use it instead.

Comment: There is an issue where calling `on_epoch_end`'s super tacks on the 'epoch_' prefix. I think this stops the tags from being able to be put on a single graph. Ex I am getting a graph for `acc, batch_acc, and epoch_acc` which is super cluttery. How do you get around this?

Comment: hi, I recommend an edit that notes if you want to remove the batch labelling, you need to override the on_batch_end method also, and just add a `pass` line so that nothing is written.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using TensorFlow 2.0, you now get this by default using the Keras TensorBoard callback. (When using TensorFlow with Keras, make sure you're using `tensorflow.keras`.)

See this tutorial :

https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras