# Monitor the Learning Rate of the InverseTimeDecay() - float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'InverseTimeDecay'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, learning-rate

My goal is to have a look at the learning rate progression of the Adam optimizer, on which I apply InverseTimeDecay schedule. So I want to check if the learning rate actually decreases.

Having checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198031/how-to-add-variables-to-progress-bar-in-keras/48206009#48206009) on stack overflow, I made similar changes in my code:

- Added this in my callback function,

```py
tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE])
```

- Added this function call based on the similar posted question:

```py
def get_lr_metric(optimizer):
    def lr(y_true, y_pred):
        return optimizer.lr
    return lr
```

- Added also the following call in the model.compile method,

```py
lr_metric = [get_lr_metric(optimizer)]

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=neural_network_parameters['model_loss'],
                  metrics=neural_network_parameters['model_metric'] + lr_metric, ) #+ lr_metric
```

However, when I start the training of the model I get the following error:

`TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'InverseTimeDecay'`

`TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`

Kindly check my [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_w3oBWlnm8tLxpBoXwfE_GC0RkQquAmr?usp=sharing) and please comment on it any changes that I should do. Also, write in the comments any additional information that I might forget to mention.

[UDPATE] - I guess that my problem is the type of optimizer.lr value. Which in my case is an InverseTimeDecay object. How can I change a type of that object to a float number? InverseTimeDecay to float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InverseTimeDecay` and every `LearningRateSchedule` instances are functions that accept a step and return the learning rate.

So the learning rate is completly predictable from the iterration/steps and there is no real need to monitor it using something like tensorboard, *but* if you really want you can use something like the following:

```py
def get_lr_metric(optimizer):
    lr = optimizer.learning_rate
    if isinstance(lr, tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
        return lr(optimizer.iterations)
    else: 
        return lr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Amit. It works as expected :)